# How to jump on specific computer using terminal on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, networking, terminal

I know few commands regarding Mac OS X's Terminal like `ls`, `cd`, `mkdir` etc.

What I want to do is switch over a network computer - how ?

What I tried is as follows -

- cd /
- ls
- cd Network
- ls ( here I found no computers )

What exactly I am missing ?

Thanks in advance for sharing your knowledge.

Sagar

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? “Jump”ing on a computer is a bit non-specific. Do you want to access another computer’s shared files? Do you want to run commands on another computer? Something else?

Comment: Yep ! Same - @Chris - I want to jump to specific / another computer's shared files. As we can explore them using through finder - I want to do the same with terminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `smbtree` to list all shares. You can then use `mount` to mount the share and cd to navigate into it. Note that you need to create the folder you want to mount the share onto. (Alternatively you can mount the share using finder and just navigate to it via `cd`. They are mounted in /Volumes).

Here's an example of mounting a share, listing its contents and unmounting it again.

```
cd /Volumes
mkdir myshare
mount -t smbfs //guest@myhost/myshare myshare
ls myshare
umount myshare
rm -r myshare
```

Comment: smbtree not working on mac

Answer (score 4):

I would use SSH to log into the remote computer, then if you want to transfer any files use scp (SSH copy).  A quick search on "SSH on OSX" should get you what you want, in general here are the steps:

```
1. open terminal on OSX
2. type "ssh [username]@[ip address of remote computer]"
```

now it's as if you opened terminal on that computer.

You will need to enable SSH in the remote computer's system preferences.

Here's one tutorial (there are many others): http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20010401050833391

Comment: You can also use Terminal's **Shell > New Remote Connection** to browse network computers and create an ssh session.

Comment: I got the error "ssh: connect to host 10.3.32.1 port 22: Connection refused"

Answer (score 2):

You can always use drag'n'drop: open terminal window, type `cd` (note space at end) connect to network share and drag it to terminal window, press enter…

Also, if you have bash 4.x, you can add `shopt -s autocd` to your `~/.bash_login` or `~/.profile` to skip typing `cd` part, just directory name.

Comment: As of Mac OS X Lion 10.7, if you drag a directory (a folder or a server) onto a terminal tab in the tab bar, Terminal will automatically issue a `cd` command. Also, if you drag onto the tab bar, it will create a new tab at that directory. Dragging onto the Terminal application icon will create a new terminal window at that location.