# Accessing shared directory path in Mac OS X Terminal

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

I'm trying to access a shared network server via terminal on the Mac.

I can obviously access directories on the same system using just the command cd (e.g. cd /Applications) but our shared network I just can't work out how to get to?

I'm starting to wonder if it's a security issue that would prevent a user from seeing/accessing it.

Comment: Mounted disks are located under /Volumes, e.g. `cd /Volumes/MySharedVolume`.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/159349/how-to-jump-on-specific-computer-using-terminal-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 52):

I suspect the volume has to be mounted first before you'll be able to acces it.

```
% cd /Volumes/[you server/volume name here]/Users/Shared/
```

Or you should use ssh.

Comment: How do you mount it though? It's open in Finder, but how to I refer to that shared volume at the command line? My /Volumes only contains a single entry for my SSD -> /

Comment: You could try `ls -l /Volumes`, normally you would see all mounted volumes listed. If it is not in the list I guess it is not mounted properly (unmount and try again?) or you may not access it.

Comment: I've seen a case where a shared folder from a windows machine went straight into /Volumes. I saw it in finder and dragged it onto the terminal.  eg /Volumes/blahfolder  no /Volumes/compblah/blahfolder

Answer (score 28):

```
cd /Volumes
```

there you will find all mounted volumes. There will also be the network-volumes.

Comment: Thanks very much! that did exactly the trick.

Are there any good reference I could use in future?

Comment: I'm sorry - I do not know any websites about questions like this one

Answer (score 7):

Use command `df` to show all mounted volume.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in your root directory under Volumes.

Answer (score 0):

In your server ( or where the shared directory is ), add a Samba user and set a password for it:

```sh
sudo smbpasswd -a [SharedVolumeName]
```

Then you can use that user ( `SharedVolumeName` ) and the password you entered to authenticate and access the shared drive.